# Load config file data automatically into class properties

Tags: c#

I want to load values from my configuration file into the Properties of specific classes automatically.
I think about it many hours but I don't find a good solution on my own.

- **Create a BaseClass with the default constructor.** So the default constructor can search for property-names which are in the config file, too. This make only sense with Entities (which only hold data). If I want to use this way for normal classes, I can not use other inheritance.
- **Create a factory which fill the properties.** Possible too, but I dont want to use the Factory everytime. This is not automatic enough.
- **Class Attributes?** Can I access the object out from the attribute, if I use a class attribute?

How do you do it in your applications? Which way (do you know better/other ways?) are the best for filling properties automatically?

**Edit**
I will try to explain it a little bit more. I have an application with many configuration data, that I store in a xml file. For example something like camera specific data, image processing options, which sps type is used and so on.

If I want put this data to the right class I have to pass through this data over and over again. Further I have to write the same code (assign value to property).
So I want a solution which make it "magically" self.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish.  If you're just loading values from a config file automatically, can't any property just get the value from the config file whenever it's referenced?  (Perhaps storing the value in a class-level member to cache it so it doesn't need to be fetched again.)  Most of what you're talking about sounds like over-complicating a config file lookup, or am I just not understanding the nature of the problem here?

Comment: You can use Configuration Manager to load values from config file like this. In class level declare 'private string value1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Configappkey"];'

Comment: Have you considered the support from System.Configuration? http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx/

Comment: `"I want a solution which make it "magically" self"` - C# doesn't support magic at this time.  (Maybe in version 7?)  What does this "configuration data" look like?  How do you access it?  Why can't you write a method which loads from the configuration values into the object and invoke it on object construction?  What's so bad about looking up values from data and assigning them to properties?

Comment: @fsimonazzi: So I have Entites again. I can not use the configurationSection without inheritance. But its a nice way if I have to use Entities.

Comment: @MitjaS.: What do you mean by "Entities" in this case?  What does `System.Configuration` have to do with inheritance?  It's really not clear what's preventing you from doing this.

Comment: @David: I thought it might give a way, so I dont need to think about how I get my values from the config file every time I need config data in an object. The link of fsimonazzi shows the following ``public class BlogSettings : ConfigurationSection`` So I cannot use this solution for every class. I need explicity classes which are holding the config values.

Comment: @MitjaS.: You don't use that solution *on the class*.  That's for creating a custom configuration section object. If you're not even loading the data from an `App.config` or `Web.config` (which your edit suggests you may not be) then that's probably not even applicable anymore. If you're storing the configuration in your own custom XML files then just write a method on the object which deserializes the data (like in the answer below) into the class. There's no reason not to be able to do this. It really sounds like you're just trying to avoid writing code, which is an odd approach to coding.

Comment: @David: At the moment I use serialization to store my data objects into a file and to fill it again. So I hoped it would give other (better) ways of doing this. But apperently not. So I will close the question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Adding a setting through the IDE atomatically creates a property that by default gets loaded from the congif file (although you can set it to load from the registry, a database, etc.).  It also supports user-level settings that can be modified and persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for Serialization: From Wikipedia:

```
In computer science, in the context of data storage, serialization is the process of 
translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (for 
example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and 
reconstructed later in the same or another computer environment.
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

So, you could just create your Configuration-class that has variour properties for the different configuration values. You then serialize that class to a file ('save the configuration') and de-serialize the file ('load the configuration').

Like this you do not need to worry about the mapping of class-properties to file-properties.

A lot of languages have already built-in helper to serialize an Object. For example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I know about serialization. But then I have a huge config class in my project and I have to assign the values at myself. I want avoid this last step.